# How to sort unicode strings alphabetically in Common Lisp?

Tags: unicode, lisp, common-lisp

This:

```
(sort '("Aaa" "Ééé" "Zzz") #'string-lessp)
;; ("Aaa" "Zzz" "Ééé")
```

is not satisfying, because "Ééé" should come before "Zzz".

How can we sort unicode strings alphabetically?

My current approach has been to create a copy of the strings, replace accentuated letters by their counterpart (with [cl-slug:asciify](https://github.com/EuAndreh/cl-slug), that calls ppcre:regexp-replace-all), sort this and display the original string back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SBCL, you have integrated support for unicode.

[String operations](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#String-operations)

Try to sort with unicode< instead of string-lessp.

Comment: Specifically, `string-lessp` should be considered to use `char-lessp` for its comparator, which in turn is defined in terms of character codes. A lisp implementation that has a locale-aware `string-lessp` is not standards-compliant.

Comment: Do you know how to do with CCL?